# PHP should I compress my API response

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, compression

Im at the point where I need to create massive reports for the data I have, to understand my data better.

For that, I need to get (for example) one of my tables. This table has about 50 parameters, and 40,000 rows. Calling the API (fetching the data) takes 0.6 seconds, but downloading the data (50MB) takes about 10-12 seconds depending on my connection.

1. Is it a good idea to run a compression on the server side data, and decompression on the client's side? (mind that some of the users run this on cheap laptops)
2. Is it a better idea to send the columns and the data sepeatly, and just fix it in JS? (some of the columns for most clients are not even filled, and it just takes space for the "key" (I encode to json))
3. If compression is a good idea, what compression can I run that will not take a long time, but will compress my data segnificantly enough so it will be faster, and the JS will decompress, and all of this in under 10 seconds? (fast compression, fast decompression, good compression)

I'd love to hear your thoughts about the subject, because I dont want to get it wrong the first time and.

Comment: ship an array instead of objects to slash bandwidth in half

Comment: put the data into a `.txt` file and then compress it into zip. compression ratio of `.txt` file is really efficient.  then let client side script parse the zip and text. but, i am not sure that the client will easily do this.

Comment: @dandavis That is point 2. Ill try that, it may even do 60-70% savings

Comment: CSV is even more compact if you have a lot of strings, especially empty ones, and it's very fast to pack/unpack. you might consider a deflate() routine and inflate it on the client: http://danml.com/js/compression.js, though the CPU time might outweigh the reduced travel time. measure twice, cut once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For most cases, you should use data compression for your API result.

GZIP is a fantastic compression method (fast, efficient) that is widely supported in most modern programming languages, and even engines. It is very simple to set, and when set, it gets the job done.